# LINQ query a database for specific id (string)

Tags: c#, database, linq, data-binding, datasource

I'm just trying to pull up only specific messages, based on the id that is stored in lblGetID
my database is Messages, created locally.  As of now, nothing, not even my GridView appears

```
var getMessage =
            from m in dbcontext.Messages.Local
            where lblGetID.Text == m.TopID 
            select m;


            Gridview1.DataSource = getMessage;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I have also tried

```
var getMessages =
            from m in dbcontext.Messages.Local
            where m.TopID == lblTopicID.Text
            select new
            {
                m.Username,
                m.Message1
            };
```

and

```
var getMessages = (from mes in dbcontext.Messages.Local
                        select mes.TopID = lblTopicID.Text);
```

Comment: Try appending `ToList()` to your query before assigning it to your `GridView1.DataSource`

Comment: yeah, as King King said `.ToList()` should do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding .ToList() as suggested in the comments it will convert the query result into list and assign it to your variable messages.